# Unable to build Spartacus 4.3 after installation

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Unable to build Spartacus 4.3 after installation. Got lot of this errors:

```
    node_modules/@spartacus/asm/asm.module.d.ts:6:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/john.doe/Projects/siko-spartacus/js-storefront/standard-store/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

    6     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<AsmModule, never>;
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@spartacus/asm/asm.module.d.ts:7:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/john.doe/Projects/siko-spartacus/js-storefront/standard-store/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

    7     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<AsmModule, never, [typeof i1.AsmComponentsModule, typeof i2.AsmCoreModule, typeof i3.AsmOccModule], never>;
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@spartacus/asm/asm.module.d.ts:8:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/john.doe/Projects/siko-spartacus/js-storefront/standard-store/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

    8     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<AsmModule>;
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

Recommended way to install Spartacus is to use Schematics. Spartacus schematics allow you to install Spartacus libraries in your project.

But before, please ensure that yours Angular project meets with specific prerequisites (**Angular CLI, Node.js and Yarn version**):
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/schematics/#prerequisites

You can also try to remove `node_modules` folder and install all dependencies once again.